# Software for Feasibility Problems

Tags: nonlinear-programming, constraint-programming, software, feasible-points

I face a feasibility problem of type

$$ c_i(\boldsymbol x) \leq 0, i = 1, \dots, \mathcal{I} \\ c_e(\boldsymbol x) = 0, e = 1, \dots, \mathcal{E} $$

where $\mathcal{I}  + \mathcal{E}  \gg \text{dim}(\boldsymbol x) \sim \mathcal{O} (10^1) $.

Currently, I solve this with [Ipopt](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/) but since it takes quite some time I thought about looking for some special feasible point solvers.

The "largest" (3) collection of feasible point solvers I could find online are mentioned in section 5.3 of [this paper](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/opt/preprints/prep2010/amna_opap_10_03.pdf).
Unfortunately, there seems to be no implementation of the therein developed algorithm (`EFNES`) online.
The [`FILTRANE`](https://www.galahad.rl.ac.uk/doc/filtrane.pdf) framework of the [Galahad package](https://github.com/ralna/GALAHAD) might be quite effective but has a nasty Fortran API which looks even for the example problem quite difficult.

EDIT: The link in the original `TRESNEI` paper is dead, but I found [this working one](https://flore.unifi.it/handle/2158/1271224).

Any suggestions besides the usual suspects from nonlinear optimization, ideally free to use within academia?

Comment: In general, a feasibility problem is not easier than an optimization problem. Therefore, there is not much point in building a code for feasibility only.

Comment: So I should not expect significant performance improvements?

Comment: To me it seems unlikely.

Comment: I often try a few different NLP solvers. They can differ a lot in performance on a given model, and it is not always easy to predict which one will be the fastest. Sometimes one can come up with an explanation afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

[Stefan Vigerske](https://github.com/svigerske) was kind enough to answer [my question](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/597#issue-1337941015) on the [Ipopt github](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt).

With [minimal changes](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/597#issuecomment-1214193598) one can basically reduce `Ipopt` to a feasibility problem solver.